# ssis data flow task refresh metadata at runtime

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am developing a SSIS package, it has a data flow task which performs the job of getting data from a SQL Query and Inserting it into a SQL Table, below attributes are obtained from user defined variables which in turn get values from a SQL Server table, and the data flow task is in a for each loop to execute all the records from the table.

1. Source Connection
2. Source Query
3. Destination Connection
4. Destination Table

Metadata is not getting refreshed for new connections/Queries/Destination Table, is there a way this can be handled at run-time automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If the Source queries and destination tables don't all have the exact same meta-data (column structure and data-types) then there is no way to use a loop to have only one dataflow that dynamically changes to handle all of the tables.

The column-mapping of a dataflow must be specified at design-time and cannot be changed at run-time.

The closest thing to what you want is BiML, which lets you dynamically create packages based on the metadata you wish to import.